# Quick source view in Intellij IDEA

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In eclipse it's possible to put mouse over a method with pressed shift button and I'll see quick source view, is it possible to do such thing in intellij idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use `View` | **Quick Definition** or the corresponding keyboard shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> on Windows).